# How to handle a case of empty parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I have the following code that I use to get size of all primitive types in the pack (I treat floats and doubles in a special way), but my program fails to compile when the pack is empty.

```
// terminating general case for T being anything else
template <class T>
size_t getSize()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

// terminating special case for T=double
template<>
size_t getSize<double>()
{
    return SIZEOF_DOUBLE;
}

// terminating special case for T=float
template<>
size_t getSize<float>()
{
    return SIZEOF_FLOAT;
}

// recursive case
template <class T, class U, class ...S>
size_t getSize()
{
    return getSize<T>() + getSize<U, S...>();
}
```

I want `getSize` to return `0` when called like

```
template <class ...T>
void foo(T... arg)
{
    size_t sizeOfTypes = getSize<T...>();
}
```

with `T={}`, i.e. `foo` is called like `foo<>();`.

Note that I don't want to modify the way the `foo` is called, the angle brackets have to stay there. Preferably I'd like to have `getSize` modified, because I use it in several functions other than `foo`. Modify `foo` as the last resort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach to solve this would be to use a couple of little structs like

```
template<typename T>
struct GetTypeSize
{
    enum { value = sizeof(T) };
};

template<>
struct GetTypeSize<float>
{
    enum { value = SIZEOF_FLOAT };
};

template<>
struct GetTypeSize<double>
{
    enum { value = SIZEOF_DOUBLE };
};

template<typename...>
struct GetSize 
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct GetSize<Head, Tail...>
{
    enum { value = GetTypeSize<Head>::value + GetSize<Tail...>::value };
};

template<typename... T>
void foo(T... arg)
{
    size_t sizeOfTypes = GetSize<T...>::value;
}
```

This has the advantage of beeing evaluated (summed up) during compile time.

I used two types of structs. One for doing the recursion (GetSize) and another for getting the actual size of the types (GetTypeSize). The specialization of `GetSize<Head, Tail...>` is instantiated as long as there is a head (the pack is not empty) and adds the size of the type in Head to the recursive call of `GetSize<Tail...>`. Once there is no Head the fallback GetSize template is used.

For an instantiation of 
`GetSize<int, double, char>` it results in

`GetTypeSize<int>::value + GetTypeSize<double>::value + GetTypeSize<char>::value + GetSize<>::value`

which then is

`sizeof(int) + SIZEOF_DOUBLE + sizeof(char) + 0`

Answer (score 3):

First a function template that converts a single type to its size, possibly with specializations:

```
template <class T>
constexpr size_t getSize_single()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

template<>
constexpr size_t getSize_single<double>()
{
    return SIZEOF_DOUBLE;
}

template<>
constexpr size_t getSize_single<float>()
{
    return SIZEOF_FLOAT;
}
```

Next, something that pack expands the pack of types into a `std::initializer_list<size_t>` of sizes, and then sums it up:

```
template <class... Ts>
constexpr size_t getSize() // constexpr for C++14 only - remove for C++11
{
    std::initializer_list<size_t> l{getSize_single<Ts>()...};
    size_t sum = 0;
    for(auto s : l) sum += s;
    return sum;
}
```

The explicit type for the `initializer_list` is needed to handle the empty pack case.

Comment: You may even use `std::accumulate`.

Comment: The beauty of template recursion is all gone, huh.
Actually, are there any benefits in iterating with initializer list over my template recursing approach, besides that it fixes the issue I have?

Comment: @FlyingHat It's IMO cleaner and easier to understand. And easier on the compiler because it has to instantiate fewer templates.

Comment: @Jarod42 `accumulate` isn't `constexpr`, though. The above can be made `constexpr` (in C++14) by merely adding the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to edit the getSize function then initialize the first one's template T to void and and add an extra template function for void type to return 0. It will look like this:

```
template <class T=void> ////A little edit here
size_t getSize()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

// terminating special case for T=double
template<>
size_t getSize<double>()
{
    return SIZEOF_DOUBLE;
}

// terminating special case for T=float
template<>
size_t getSize<float>()
{
    return SIZEOF_FLOAT;
}
/////Extra entry for void type
template<>
size_t getSize<void>()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When foo<>() is called, T will be set to void by default and this last function will be called instead of the others and it will return 0 as the size.